# Graph API - Daemon App with Access to a Personal Microsoft Account (Azure AD V2.0 endpoint)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to create a Daemon (code-only, server-only) app that can access my Personal Microsoft Account.  I cannot figure out how to get an Access_Token that does not expire (or a refresh_token).

I can create a working non-expiring (admin logs in only once) Daemon app for my Business (Office 365) Account using the "adminconsent" endpoint detailed here:   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds/ or here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tsmatsuz/2016/10/07/application-permission-with-v2-endpoint-and-microsoft-graph/.  Unfortunately, I cannot use the "adminconsent" endpoint with my personal account -- returns "This operation can only be performed by an administrator" error.  Is there a way I can enable adminconsent for my personal account?

OR

For my personal account, I can use the "authorize" endpoint (as detailed here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-scopes/) and it returns a code (that expires) that can be used to obtain the "access_token"; which works fine in Graph API -- until the access_token expires (3600 seconds).  It does not return a "refresh_token".  So, after the code/token expires, it then requires the user to log in again.   How can I use the authorize endpoint to then obtain tokens that can be refreshed via code only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the `offline_access` scope to get a refresh token. Be sure to replace your refresh token with the new one that comes back each time you refresh.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I am now able to get the refesh token.   I overlooked the "Offline Access" section in the documentation because the title did not seem related to getting a refresh token.