# Microsoft Personal account data with client credentials flow

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices

The use case is quiet simple, I want to read and write to calendars on a *daemon* (backend workflow) from personal Microsoft account or azure AD account.

Then I registered an *Enterprise application* in Azure Active Directory admin center with:

- the account type **« Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox) »**.
- permissions on read write on calendars + read on user
- a generated client secret
- a redirect uri

For all accounts from the same Azure Active Directory, the authentication with the client secret and the impersonation of the targeted email works well.

But for personal Microsoft accounts it is not. If I understood correctly I need to use the client credentials flow to grant the user. Then the user need to go on the admin consent url as explained: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=<client_id>&state=12345&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>`.

But when logging in with a personal account it results in a redirection to the specified redirect uri with the error:

```
AADSTS500200: User account '{EmailHidden}' is a personal Microsoft account.
Personal Microsoft accounts are not supported for this application unless explicitly invited to an organization.
Try signing out and signing back in with an organizational account.
```

### Research

I tried some solution of the error AADSTS500200 with this article: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/SupportArticles-docs/blob/main/support/azure/active-directory/error-code-AADSTS50020-user-account-identity-provider-does-not-exist.md (note that the error number is missing a last zero). But I still receive the same error or an other error *Needs admin approval* when the personal account is invited.

[*Needs admin approval* (french only)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSLYl.png)

### Question

Is it possible to read data on personal Microsoft account ? How to achieve this ? Is there any other way ?

Comment: Can you confirm whether the guest user was invited? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-code-aadsts50020-user-account-identity-provider-does-not-exist#solution-invite-the-guest-user

Comment: Yes. I invited him in Azure AD, confirmed the email link from personal account and then had another issue: "Administrator approval required" (see picture in the edited post)

Comment: Can you please attach the snip in English?

Comment: Does the error look anything similar to [this](https://i.imgur.com/cYK5AX3.png)?

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to change the language - no dropdown, tried to clear the cache or update the setting account language but it changed nothing.
This is the exact translation @Rukmini !

Comment: Can you confirm whether you have clicked on **Accept** while granting admin consent like [this](https://i.imgur.com/jnO7ytY.png)? by checking on consent on behalf of organization?

Comment: @Rukmini you are trying with a `@onmicrosoft.com` account with your first picture and my issue is with a personal account `@hotmail.com`.
With the accounts of the same AD it works great with the client secret

Comment: I tried to do the same with my [**personal account**](https://i.imgur.com/AbLZrJl.png) too and it works for me.

Comment: Interesting! Did you even need to invite your personal account ? What are the list of you permissions ?

Comment: I have granted `Calendars.Read` Application permission to the Azure AD App.

Comment: when you say Microsoft Personal account. do you mean the @outlook.com  email without having Azure Portal registered? You need the Azure portal to grant admin consent.

Comment: @Rukmini In my opinion the screenshot you have shared is still an organizational account where in you have your own tenant id and access to Azure Portal

Comment: I added as well Calendars.Read in delegated mode (previously added in application same issue): https://i.imgur.com/RPsvnFj.png
How did you succeed this prompt. Is it the adminconsent page https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent ?

Comment: Yeah, I used `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=ClientID` to grant admin consent.

Comment: Thanks @AkshayG. Exactly when I said Microsoft Personal account, it is a basic account freshly create from outlook / hotmail and where I wanted to have calendar access for my backend application.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46938623/4018180

Comment: Try using authorization-code flow and check if it works!

Comment: Thanks both, I will try using authorization code. But from the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows) only *Client credentials* is marked as supported for *Daemon*. Is it possible to send back the refresh token via this authorization-code flow to the backend and use `acquireTokenSilently` from MSAL to read the calendar every days without the need to redo the authorization ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use Microsoft personal accounts with the client credentials flow.

The solution is to use the authorization-code flow and use the scope `offline_access` during the authorization request and the token request. So that the `refresh_token` that can be used to regenerate new `refresh_token`s.